# Non-graphing calculator for normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, calculator

I am interested in finding a non-graphing calculator that helps find the z value give the area under the curve. For example, I want to find a value of a such that $P(Z \leq a) = 0.75$. I am having a casio fx 115es plus. I have done some research online and it seems to me that TI calculator has a built-in function call "Invnorm", but it is a waste of money to buy such a product just for the invnorm function. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why does it need to be a calculator? This sort of thing can be done on a phone now.

Comment: probably for exams, where phones are forbidden but calculators often are not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mode 3 (DIST mode) has normal density, cumulative distribution and inverse cumulative distribution functions (and similar for binomial and Poisson distributions)

See page E-47 of the manual (page 48 of the pdf) at http://support.casio.com/storage/en/manual/pdf/EN/004/fx-115_991ES_PLUS_C_EN.pdf